# Vertical spacing of equations using align environment following short texts

Tags: spacing, equations, align, amsmath

The 'align' environment is awesome and I think it can almost replace the default 'equation' and 'eqnarray' environments. However, I find the vertical spacing of the align equations a little troubling to me.

I observe that if the equation follows a long text line, 'align' and 'equation' do the same spacing; however, if the equation is after a short text line, 'equation' does some compression while 'align' doesn't, so the former results in a better-looking equation.

Here is an example. Is there anyway for 'align' to adjust the spacing the same as 'equation'?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
Using \textit{equation}:
\begin{equation}
x = 1
\end{equation}
Spacing is OK.

\smallskip
(Using \textit{align}):
\begin{align}
x = 1
\end{align}
Spacing is too much.

\bigskip
\textbf{Another Example}

Using \textit{equation}: (long text long text long text)
\begin{equation}
x = 1
\end{equation}
Spacing is OK. (long text long text long text long text)

\smallskip
Using \textit{align}: (long text long text long text long text) 
\begin{align}
x = 1
\end{align}
Spacing is the same. (long text long text long text long text)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can set the lengths `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` to your liking.

Comment: The issue is that `align` isn't respecting the `\abovedisplayshortskip`/`\belowdisplayshortskip`. I don't recall if there's a solution to this.

Comment: The answer to this question can be found in subsection 3.1.5 (p. 8) of the manual of the `mathtools` package (type `texdoc mathtool` at a terminal emulator prompt to bring it up).

Answer (score 4):

The `SwapAboveDisplaySkip`command from `mathtools`  (mentioned by @Gustavo Mezzetti in his comment) doesn't work with `multline`, nor `equation`.

The `\useshortskip` from `nccmath` (to be used just before the environment, contrary to the `mathtools` solution, which has to be used at the beginning of the environment) works:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
Using \textit{equation}:
\begin{equation}
x = 1
\end{equation}
Spacing is OK.

\smallskip
(Using \textit{align}):\useshortskip
\begin{align}
x = 1
\end{align}
Spacing is OK.

\bigskip
(Using \textit{multline}):\useshortskip
\begin{multline}
x =a + b + c + d\\ + f +e +g + h
\end{multline}
Spacing is OK.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for providing this solution. It works perfectly. Also your comments are very educating to me.

Answer (score 2):

In the end, I’ve decided to expand [my comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375170/vertical-spacing-of-equations-using-align-environment-following-short-texts#comment928312_375170) to an anwer.

Many of the environments that the `amsmath` package defines for displaying math do not exploit the “display short skip” mechanism that TeX implements at “machine-level”; this is because, from a TeXnical point of view, those environments do not typeset a “displayed equation”, but rather something more similar to a `list` environment.  Anyway, the `mathtoos` package provide a *partial* workaround for this: if the very first thing inside a display environment is the command `\SwapAboveDisplaySkip`, then the display will be precede by the `\abovedisplayshortskip` space, and not by `\abovedisplayskip`.  This solution is only partial because it is *not* automatic: a `\SwapAboveDisplaySkip` command must be manually inserted wherever it is needed.  Finally, it should be remarked that `\SwapAboveDisplaySkip` cannot be used with the `equation` and `multline` environments—but neither it needs to!

Here’s a complete, compilable example:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{mathtools} % also loads "amsmath"



\begin{document}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

Using \texttt{equation}:
\begin{equation}
    x = 1
\end{equation}
Spacing is OK.

\medskip
Using \texttt{align}:
\begin{align}
    x = 1
\end{align}
Spacing is too much.

\medskip
Using \verb|\SwapAbove...|:
\begin{align}
    \SwapAboveDisplaySkip
    x = 1
\end{align}
Now the spacing is correct.

\bigskip
\textbf{Another Example}

Using \texttt{equation} (long text long text long text):
\begin{equation}
    x = 1
\end{equation}
Spacing is OK.

\smallskip
Using \texttt{align} (long text long text long text long text): 
\begin{align}
    x = 1
\end{align}
Spacing is the same.

\bigskip
\textbf{But Beware:}

Using \verb|\SwapAboveDisplaySkip| (long text long text long text long text):
\begin{align}
    \SwapAboveDisplaySkip
    x = 1
\end{align}
Now the spacing is wrong again (too little)!

\end{document}
```

The following is the output I get:

[image: Output of the code]