# Too much space above align-environment if very little text prior to it

Tags: spacing, equations, align, tcolorbox

I am using the tcolorbox package for some boxes which often contain equations. If there is some text prior to the equation- or align-environment which is long enough to force the equation to be set down a bit, there is no problem in spacing. Both boxes have the same height (see first picture).
[image: There is no problem, when there is enough text prior to the align-environment.]

But if there is not enough text above it, or no text at all, the equation-environment appears a bit further up, which is just right. But the align-environment does not behave like this, it has got too much space above it. That is why the two boxes differ in height (see second picture).
[image: While the equation-environment appears a bit further up, the align-environment does not behave like this, if there is not enough text prior to the environment.]

This is my MWE, which creates the boxes shown in the pictures:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,a4paper,12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\definecolor{maple-hblau}{RGB}{58,126,171}
\colorlet{colexample}{maple-hblau!75}
\newtcolorbox{examplebox}{%
empty,title={Example},attach boxed title to top left,
boxed title style={empty,size=minimal,toprule=2pt,top=4pt,overlay={\draw[colexample,line width=2pt] ([yshift=-1pt]frame.north west)--([yshift=-1pt]frame.north east);}},
coltitle=colexample,fonttitle=\footnotesize\bfseries,
before=\par\medskip\noindent,parbox=false,boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=3mm,top=4pt,
overlay={\draw[colexample,line width=1pt] ([yshift=-1pt]title.north east)--([xshift=-0.5pt,yshift=-1pt]title.north-|frame.east)--([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south east)--(frame.south west); },
}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn

% long text prior to the align-environment -> no problem
\begin{examplebox}
  Align*-Environment:
  \begin{align*}
      \frac{5}{2} = \frac{15}{6}    
    \end{align*}
\end{examplebox}

\newpage

% long text prior to the equation-environment, for comparison
\begin{examplebox}
  Equation*-Environment:
  \begin{equation*}
    \frac{21}{9} = \frac{7}{3}
  \end{equation*}
\end{examplebox}

\newpage

% not enough text prior to the align-environment -> too much white space above align
\begin{examplebox}
  Align*:
  \begin{align*}
      \frac{5}{2} = \frac{15}{6}    
    \end{align*}
\end{examplebox}

\newpage

% the same amount of text prior to the equation-environment, for comparison
\begin{examplebox}
  Equation*:
  \begin{equation*}
    \frac{21}{9} = \frac{7}{3}
  \end{equation*}
\end{examplebox}

\end{document}
```

Is there a reason for the align-environment behaving like this or is this a bug?

And the more important question: How do I change this behavior of align, so that the box with the align-environment and just a bit text above it is as big as the box with the equation-environment besides it, so there is less space above the align-environment? Best would be to define this behavior globally, so I don't have to insert some command every time there is the align-environment and very little text above it.

Comment: LaTeX's single-line equation environments -- `equation` and `equation*` -- use either `\abovedisplayskip` or `\abovedisplayshortskip`, depending on the length of the line that immediately precedes the environment. In contrast, the multiline equation environments of the `amsmath` package use only `\abovedispkayskip`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known problem: `align` doesn't use the shortskips.

The solution is to load the [`nccmath`](https://ctan.org/pkg/nccmath) package (part of [`ncctools`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ncctools)), and to use the `\useshortskip` command before `align`:

```latex
\documentclass[ngerman,a4paper,12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\definecolor{maple-hblau}{RGB}{58,126,171}
\colorlet{colexample}{maple-hblau!75}
\newtcolorbox{examplebox}{%
empty,title={Example},attach boxed title to top left,
boxed title style={empty,size=minimal,toprule=2pt,top=4pt,overlay={\draw[colexample,line width=2pt] ([yshift=-1pt]frame.north west)--([yshift=-1pt]frame.north east);}},
coltitle=colexample,fonttitle=\footnotesize\bfseries,
before=\par\medskip\noindent,parbox=false,boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=3mm,top=4pt,
overlay={\draw[colexample,line width=1pt] ([yshift=-1pt]title.north east)--([xshift=-0.5pt,yshift=-1pt]title.north-|frame.east)--([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south east)--(frame.south west); },
}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn

% long text prior to the align-environment -> no problem
\begin{examplebox}
    Align*-Environment:%\useshortskip
    \begin{align*}
        \frac{5}{2} = \frac{15}{6}
    \end{align*}
\end{examplebox}

\newpage

% long text prior to the equation-environment, for comparison
\begin{examplebox}
    Equation*-Environment:
    \begin{equation*}
    \frac{21}{9} = \frac{7}{3}
    \end{equation*}
\end{examplebox}

\newpage

% not enough text prior to the align-environment -> too much white space above align
\begin{examplebox}
    Align*:\useshortskip
    \begin{align*}
        \frac{5}{2} = \frac{15}{6}
    \end{align*}
\end{examplebox}

\newpage

% the same amount of text prior to the equation-environment, for comparison
\begin{examplebox}
    Equation*:
    \begin{equation*}
    \frac{21}{9} = \frac{7}{3}
    \end{equation*}
\end{examplebox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The solution is not to load the `nccmath` package but rather to use `equation` instead of `align` for single-line formulas.  I would argue that `align` does not use the short skips *by design*.

Comment: You're right, but I suppose the O.P. meant he really needs to use a multilined equation.

Comment: Then there should also be a large skip around the equation.

Comment: I know cases where, aesthecically, it's too large. For instance when align is used just because the equation is  too long to fit on a single line.

Comment: "This is a known problem". I think this claim is too negative and too dismissive. The problem lies not in the `amsmath` package's multiline-math environments not using `\abovedisplayshortskip` and `\belowdisplayshortskip`. Instead, as Henri Menke has already pointed out, the real problem lies with those users who employ `align` and `gather` for single-line displayed equations despite the `amsmath` package providing numerous warnings *not* to do so. If anything, the authors of the `amsmath` package were guilty of having been too optimistic about users actually heeding such warnings.

Comment: Of course, I’d like to use `align` only for multiline expressions. Is there a reason for `align` not using `\abovedisplayshortskip`? Is there a possibility to redefine `align` so it does use `\abovedisplayshortskip` (or anything else defined globally, so I don’t have to insert `\useshortskip` in all places with too much space manually)?

Comment: the failure of `amsmath` to use `\abovedisplayshortskip` for multi-line display environments has been on the bugs list for a very long time.  the cause is the necessity of multi-line displays to measure the width in order to accommodate equation numbers; no account has been taken for the `*`ed version.  i'm sure a good answer has been given for this already, but i'm unable to find it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton  A good but perhaps not perfect answer to this problem is user wea0's mid- to late-August 2017 TeX StackExchange [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386052/295947).