# Align and twocolumn: too high on right column

Tags: align, amsmath, two-column

I'm making a collection of formulas for students. It has to be dense and fit on one page, so I decided to use `\twocolumn`. However, I hate it when things don't look nice and aligned, so the following photo is very frustrating.

This is from the top of the page
[image: Misaligned columns]

Notice how the right column is far too high. I want them to be nicely aligned on the top.
Here is a reproducable example. I don't really know any tricks to make this minimal, heh

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks%
\begin{document}
\def\euler{e^{i\pi} &= -1}
\begin{align}
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    35e^{i\pi} & = -35 \\
    36e^{i\pi} & = -36 \\
    37e^{i\pi} & = -37 \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add in `\usepackage{nccmath}`. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386266/121944).

Comment: Works! Want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386266/121944), you need to add the package `nccmath` and also use `\useshortskip` before `align`. According to page 3 of the [documentation](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ncctools/doc/nccmath.pdf), "a manual replacement of the normal skip to the short skip is required in some cases". Apparently you found a case.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath} % added this
\allowdisplaybreaks%
\begin{document}
\def\euler{e^{i\pi} &= -1}
\useshortskip % added this
\begin{align}
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    35e^{i\pi} & = -35 \\
    36e^{i\pi} & = -36 \\
    37e^{i\pi} & = -37 \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler             \\
    \euler
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]