# Too short spacing of `cases` with `\useshortskip`

Tags: spacing, cases, nccmath

[This](https://www.overleaf.com/read/sfgzzjbkyypt) is an Overleaf MWE.

Code from the example:

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{nccmath}    % align & gather doesn't use shortskip: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386266/206774
\useshortskip           % nccmath seems to fix that even without this line


\begin{document}

1st case case case case case case case case 

\[\begin{cases}
    D: \text{wheel diameter} \\
    A = l \sin{\beta_1} \\
\end{cases}\]

2nd case case case case case case case case 

\[\begin{cases}
    D: \text{wheel diameter} \\
    A = l \sin{\beta_1} \\
\end{cases}\]

\end{document}
```

This is the problem:

[image]

It seems that only the first `cases` is affected.

Comment: To me, using `\shortskip` in the present context is rather questionable. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mico `align` in my project is placed too far from the previous paragraph. `\useshortskip` fix this for me.

Comment: never leave a blank line before a displayed equation. That is causing the bad spacing (`\useshortskip` can not fix that)

Comment: `\useshortskip` only applies to the _next_ equation. So only the first one here. It is usually applied immediately before, using it in the preamble is a bit odd, if not exactly an error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I learn LaTeX by reading Overleaf examples. I think I made a huge huge mistake, for not thoroughly reading some mathmode guides. I always put newline around non-inline equations.