# Misplaced \noalign: mathtools's SwapAboveDisplaySkip does not work with autonum package

Tags: mathtools, autonum

I would like to use `\SwapAboveDisplaySkip` from the `mathtools` package to fix the vertical space above `align` environments. Unfortunately, this does not seem to work when loading the `autonum` package:

> ! Misplaced \noalign.
>   \SwapAboveDisplaySkip ->\noalign

`autonum` needs to be loaded because I would like to label equations only if they are referenced (not shown in the MWE, but required in the document) and the `mathtools` option does not work when loading the `cleveref` package.

Here is an **MWE** that produces the described error. Removing either `\usepackage{autonum}` or `\SwapAboveDisplaySkip` makes the error go away.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{autonum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}

Text
\begin{align}
\SwapAboveDisplaySkip
A &= B
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `autonum` package inserts some assignments just after the original code executed for `align`, which makes `\noalign` appear in a wrong place, because those assignments are executed in the first cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `autonum` package patches `align` and the other environments to do something (dangerous) just after the alignment is started, so the trick used by `mathtools` becomes impossible.

Technically, the code inserted by `autonum` is performed in the first cell of the alignment, but `\SwapAboveDisplayskip` *must* be the first item, because it uses `\noalign`. Actually it has not to be the first item, provided it is only preceded by other `\noalign` items.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{autonum}

\makeatletter
% fix autonum code
\newtoggle{autonum@equation@toggle}
\def\autonum@startChangeEnvironment#1#2{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{split}{%
    \GlobalLetLtxMacro\autonum@outerMathEnvironmentLabel\label
  }{%
    \autonum@saveSubcommands
  }%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{equation}{%
    \global\toggletrue{autonum@equation@toggle}%
  }{%
    \global\togglefalse{autonum@equation@toggle}%
  }%
  \csuse{autonum@#1Old}#2%
  \iftoggle{autonum@equation@toggle}{}{\noalign\bgroup}%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{split}{%
    \GlobalLetLtxMacro\label\autonum@outerMathEnvironmentLabel
  }{%
    \autonum@patchSubcommands{#1}%
  }%
  \iftoggle{autonum@equation@toggle}{}{\egroup}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}

Text Text Text Text Text
\begin{equation}
A = B
\end{equation}
Text Text Text Text Text
\begin{align}
\SwapAboveDisplaySkip
A &= B
\end{align}
Text Text Text Text Text
\begin{align}
A &= B
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, this breaks when adding `Text Text Text Text Text \begin{equation} A = B \end{equation}` right before the end of the document (`! Misplaced \noalign.
\autonum@startChangeEnvironment ...Old}#2\noalign`).

Comment: @jpmath The new version works also with `equation` (the `\noalign` is inserted conditionally). Please, do other tests and feel free to ask again if something goes wrong.

Comment: I have not done thorough testing, but using it in a very large document it seemed to work fine. You probably don't know a way to automate the short skips before align either (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385787/61658) do you?

Comment: @Patrick Häcker Do you think it would be possible to implement that into your package?

Comment: @jpmath I sent mail to the author of `autonum` about this.

Answer (score 0):

No problem, of course, using the `showonlyrefs` boolean from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}

Text text text text text text%\useshortskip
\begin{align}
\SwapAboveDisplaySkip
A &= B
\end{align}

More text More text
\begin{align}
A &= B
\end{align}
Still more text

\end{document}
```

If you really need to use `autonum`, you can use the `\useshortskip`  from `nccmath` in the place of `\SwapAboveDisplayskip`, like this:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{autonum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}

Text text text text text text \useshortskip
\begin{align}
A &= B
\end{align}

More text More text
\begin{align}
A &= B
\end{align}
Still more text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The reason for `autonum` is to straighten up some difficulties with `showonlyrefs`.

Comment: I didn't know that.  In this case, `\useshortskip` from `nccmath` seems to be compatible with `autonum`.

Comment: `\useshortskip` works very well, despite the need of an additional package - which is why I tend to prefer egregs solution if it can be fixed. Too bad that the short skips before `align` environments can not be automated (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385787/61658).

Comment: @jpmath: One may ask whether it's better to have a longer preamble (or a personal macros file), or to load one more package. On the other hand, `nccmath`defines some other goodies, like very useful `medium size` math macros (`\mfrac, \mint, ...`) and environments, an optional argument for `\intertext`to control the vertical spacing of this command.

Comment: I totally agree, this decision should be made on a case-by-case basis. I had a look into `nccmath` and noticed that I currently would have no usage for it besides from `\useshortskip`. Hence I opted for the macro.