# Question about vertical spaces used by \[...\] and align* and how to reduce these

Tags: spacing, equations, align

When using `\[...\]` I noticed sometimes the vertical space used is larger than in other cases that also uses `\[...\]`. I do not understand why this is the case. Here is an example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\begin{document}
The solution found in (1) now becomes%
\[
f\left(  x\right)  e^{bx}=F\left(  x\right)
\]
Then (1) becomes%
\[
u\left(  t,x\right)  =e^{-at}e^{bx}f\left(  x-ct\right)
\]
QED.
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The first equation uses more space above and below than the second equation.

**Question:** Is it possible to make `\[..\]` use smaller vertical space above and below the equation, just like in case B?

Also, when using `align`, the spaces in both cases now becomes the same.

**Question:** Can one reduce this vertical space as well to be as in `case B` above?

Here is MWE for align

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\begin{document}
The solution found in (1) now becomes%
\begin{align*}
f\left(  x\right)  e^{bx}&=F\left(  x\right)
\end{align*}
Then (1) becomes%
\begin{align*}
u\left(  t,x\right)  =e^{-at}e^{bx}f\left(  x-ct\right)
\end{align*}
QED.
\end{document}
```

Here screen shot side by side showing the difference:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

ps. I know about `savetrees` package, but it had some side effects I did not like so I do not want to use it for this purpose.

Using Tl 2019

Comment: (i) change `\abovedisplayskip`, (ii) use only `amsmath` environments which not consider `\abovedisplayshortskip` . See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385774/amsmath-redefine-align-to-support-abovedisplayshortskip-and-belowdisplayshor/386052

Comment: equation has a build in space saving feature that align does not (reason why I always instruct users to typeset one-liners with `equation(*)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two solutions to use every now and then `\abovedisplayshortskip` in the place of `\abovedisplayskip`:  the `\useshortskip` command from `nccmath` just before entering the amsmath environment, or `\SwapAboveDisplaySkip` from `mathtools`  *after* entering the environment. Note however that if the line above is too long, the result can be ugly.

Demo:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

The solution found in (1) now becomes%
\[
f\left( x\right) e^{bx}=F\left( x\right)
\]
Then (1) becomes\
\[
u\left( t,x\right) =e^{-at}e^{bx}f\left( x-ct\right)
 \]
QED.
\newpage

The solution found in (1) now becomes%
\begin{align*}
f\left( x\right) e^{bx}&=F\left( x\right)
\end{align*}
Then (1) becomes\useshortskip%
\begin{align*}\SwapAboveDisplaySkip
u\left( t,x\right) =e^{-at}e^{bx}f\left( x-ct\right)
\end{align*}
QED. \bigskip

Then (1) becomes the following equation:\useshortskip%
\begin{align*}
u\left( t,x\right) =e^{-at}e^{bx}f\left( x-ct\right)
\end{align*}
QED.

\end{document}
```

[image]