# Vertical spacing around equations containing tikz pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, equations

I use a lot of tikz diagrams in my equations, but I've noticed the spacing around them is weirdly inconsistent. This probably isn't a tikz issue but using tikz diagrams makes it particularly noticeable.

My question is both "how can I change this" and "*should* I change this?" The spacing looks weird to me but maybe there are good reasons for it that I don't know about.

Consider the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

A diagram:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current  bounding  box.center)]
        \node[draw]{foo};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}

Another diagram, in another equation:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current  bounding  box.center)]
        \node[draw]{foo};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}

Yet another diagram, in yet another equation:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current  bounding  box.center)]
        \node[draw]{foo};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Here is its output:

[image]

There is noticeably more space after equation 2 than there is after equation 1. I think this is because the text "A diagram:" is shorter than the text "Another diagram, in another eqution:", because if I make them the same then the spacing becomes the same. So I expect that this behaviour is by design.

However, somehow when the equations contain diagrams like this it tends to look a bit odd. So I'm wondering if there is a sensible way to change this behaviour, or whether it's something I should just put up with and leave alone.

Comment: Looks like duplicate of [fontsize - How to fix the vertical spacing above and under equations? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519895/how-to-fix-the-vertical-spacing-above-and-under-equations). set `abovedisplayshortskip` to the same as `abovedisplayskip` and similar to `below`. Nothing specific to TikZ.

Comment: @user202729 hmm, yeah, it's the same issue. I know there's nothing specific to tikz, but my point here was that it looks particularly noticeable with box-ish diagrams rather than math expressions. There is a difference between the questions though: that user is convinced they want to change the spacing and is asking how to, whereas I'm also asking "*should* I change this?". I'll edit to make that clear.